# View script performed when click a button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using the Chrome developer tool, how can I view the script that will be run when I click a button on a web page? Is it possible, or will I have to use some special tools?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for a way to see what JS is sniffing for a particular event on a particular element?

Comment: that's right, is there a way to view/search for that among all the scripts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome, do a **right-click -> inspect element** on the element (in this case the button) that you want to view event handlers for. On the right (next to the HTML) you should see a window with some CSS. If you scroll all the way down, there is an "event listeners" section. Expand it and you can view handlers for the various events.

Note that I have not always found this useful; it does not always show all of the handlers that are sniffing your element. It does do what you are looking for, but sometimes it's best to just write to console (`console.log()`) in your code to find out what handlers are being called.

Let me know if you have any questions on this. Good luck! :)